# Program is stopping even though conditions haven't been met

Tags: python, python-3.x

It prints "that wasn't an option" When I press Y or N even though I have it

I have it set as != (not equal to)

```
if c.upper() != 'N' or "Y": 
    print ("that wasn't an option")
if c.upper() != 'N' or "Y": 
    sys.exit()
```

Whole code

```
import sys
c = input('do you like piza? Y or N:')
if c.upper() != 'N' or "Y": print ("that wasn't an option")
if c.upper() != 'N' or "Y": sys.exit()
if c.upper() == 'Y':
print ('Me To') 
if c.upper() == 'N': print ("really i thought everybody likes piza.")
if c.upper() == 'N': sys.exit()
name = input("sooo what's ur name? ")
print("that a pretty good name i guess ")`
```

Comment: `if c.upper() != 'N' or "Y" - is wrong,  `if c.upper() != 'N' or c.upper() != "Y"

Comment: or: `if c.upper() in {'Y', 'N'}: ...`.

Comment: `if ... or "Y"` is always truthy, because one of your conditions is just `"Y"`, and `"Y"` is truthy. You mean `if c.upper() not in { 'N','Y'}:`

Comment: @Basalex You mean `and`, not `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had made a mistake by just putting the `or` statement without specifying a condition. Instead of just `or`ing a value, you have to specify another condition. Here I have provided an example how it should be.

```
import sys
c = input('do you like piza? Y or N:')
if c.upper() != 'N' or c.upper() != "Y": 
    print ("that wasn't an option")
if c.upper() != 'N' or c.upper() != "Y": 
    sys.exit()
if c.upper() == 'Y':
    print ('Me To') 
if c.upper() == 'N': 
    print ("really i thought everybody likes piza.")
if c.upper() == 'N': 
    sys.exit()
name = input("sooo what's ur name? ")
print("that a pretty good name i guess ")
```

You could also slightly refactor the code, by combining the last 2 `if`s like so:

```
if c.upper() == 'N':
    print("really i thought everybody likes piza.")
    sys.exit()
```

and also the 1st two `if`s like so:

```
if c.upper() != 'N' or c.upper() != "Y": 
    print ("that wasn't an option")
    sys.ext()
```

**EDIT**

The `or` should be replaced with an `and`, otherwise that check makes no sense.

Credit to *khelwood* for pointing it out.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `c.upper() != 'N' or c.upper() != "Y"` is always true. You mean `and`, not `or`.

Comment: @khelwood oh good catch, I was looking syntax errors only will update now